# Write a letter in LaTex

Tags: graphics, letters, letterspacing, letterhead

I'm new to LaTeX and I'm trying to write the letter in attachment. Even if it is so simple, it's driving me crazy. I'm not able to put the logo only in the first page and not in the others, trying not to let LaTeX  put things where he wants and not where I want. Can someone give me some tips?

[image: Page One]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX could you please provide a minimal working example of what you have so far?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: From the images you provided, it did not seem like the logo was on both pages.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's an example that includes a file with the [.eps extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulated_PostScript) for greater image quality. It's placed within a `figure` environment that allows us to properly place it and also add a caption (if needed).

The space for the word `oggetto` is achieved with the `description` environment.

Of course, you'll need to replace `image_name` with the name of your logo (in .eps format). If the image is in the same directory as your .tex file, you don't need to specify the extension.

[image: example image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum} % random text
\usepackage{graphicx} % for including images
\usepackage{enumitem} % for description options
\usepackage{epstopdf} % for the .eps file (logo)
\usepackage{caption} % for the caption without the "Figure 1"

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % no indent for whole document

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \scalebox{.3}{\includegraphics{image_name}}
    \caption*{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{description}[font=\normalfont,leftmargin=5em,labelwidth=5em,labelsep=0pt]
\item[Oggetto:] Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et, tellus.
\end{description}

\lipsum[2-10]
\end{document}
```